Hyperbolic structure on $T^2 \times [0,1]$
It is a direct corollary of Preissman theorem that for any compact manifold M, $T^2 \times M$ admits no hyperbolic structure, the requirement of compactness is mainly because the following theorem which we use to construct a unique invariant geodesic of every Deck transformation (action of $\pi_1(M)$ on universal cover), in the proof1 or proof2 of Preissman's result.

Let (M, g) be a compact connected Riemannian manifold which is
not simply connected. Then in each free homotopy class, there is a length-minimizing
curve and the curve is a (closed) geodesic.

but when M is a manifold with boundary, I want to know how this fails. Take $T^2 \times [0,1]$ as an example, on Turston The Geometry and Topology of Three-Manifolds 5.5 he said that it has a hyperbolic structure. The question is:
1.I want to know how the above theorem fails, i.e. in which free homotopy class there is no closed geodesic, or somewhere else fails instead in the proof of Preissman theorem.
2.I want to know what is the hyperbolic structure on $T^2 \times [0,1]$.

the metric $e^{2z}(\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2) + \mathrm{d}z^2$ is hyperbolic on $T^2\times [0,1]$, where $z$ is the $[0,1]$ coordinate

Hyperbolic structures on manifolds with boundary are tricky beasts (I suppose that this is the lesson of the example in Thurston's book). You might be aware: if you add an appropriate hypothesis then the conclusion might change. For instance: $T^2 \times [0,1]$ has no hyperbolic structure with geodesic boundary; also $T^2 \times [0,1]$ has no convex hyperbolic structure.

Construction of a hyperbolic structure on $T^2\times [0,1]$
In horospherical coordinates, the $3$-dimensional hyperbolic space is given by $\mathbb{H}^3 = (\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}, g)$, where $g$ is
$$
g = e^{2z}(\mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2) + \mathrm{d}z^2,
$$
with $z$ is the third coordinate.
The action $\mathbb{Z}^2 \curvearrowright \mathbb{H}^3$ given by
$$
(n,m)\cdot(x,y,z) = (x+n,y+m,z)
$$
is isometric.
The hyperbolic metric thus descends to the quotient
$$
\mathbb{H}^3 / \mathbb{Z}^2 = T^2\times \mathbb{R}
$$
as an hyperbolic metric, which we still call $g$.
Restricting the $z$ coordinate to $[0,1]$, we have then built a compact manifold with boundary $M=T^2 \times [0,1]$ with an hyperbolic metric
$$
g = e^{2z}g_{T^2} + \mathrm{d}z^2,
$$
where $g_{T^2}$ is the usual flat metric on $T^2 = \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$.
Construction of a curve minimising the length in its homotopy class but which is not a geodesic
Consider a curve $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$, $t\in [0,1]$.
Then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{length}_M (\gamma)
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{e^{2z(t)}(x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2) + z'(t)^2} \mathrm{d}t \\
& \geqslant \int_0^1e^{z(t)} \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} \mathrm{d}t \\
& \geqslant e^{\min_{s\in [0,1]} z(s)} \int_0^1\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}\mathrm{d}t \\
& \geqslant \mathrm{length}_{T^2}(\pi (\gamma)),
\end{align}
where $\pi \colon M \to T^2$ is the projection on the first factor.
Moreover, the equality is achieved if and only if $z'(t) \equiv 0$ and $\min_{[0,1]} z = 0$, that is if and only if $z(t)$ is constant equal to $0$.
In particular, a curve $\gamma$ always satisfies
$$
\mathrm{length}_M(\gamma) \geqslant \mathrm{length}_{T^2} (\pi(\gamma)) \geqslant  \inf_{c \in [\pi(\gamma)]}\mathrm{length}_{T^2}(c).
$$
Notice that any curve in $M$ is homotopic to a curve with constant $z$-coordinate.
Since the curve $c(t) = (t,0)$ minimises the length in its homotopy class on $T^2$, it follows that the curve
$$
\gamma_0(t) = (t,0,0), \quad t\in[0,1]
$$
is minimising in its homotopy class.
Notice that $\gamma_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is parametrised by arc-length, and thus, to show that it is not a geodesic, it suffices to show that it does not satisfy the equation of geodesics.
Since the metric is diagonal, the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^z_{xx}$ satisfies
$$
\Gamma^z_{xx} = -\frac{1}{2}g^{zz} \partial_z g_{xx} = - e^{2z}.
$$
Finally, one easily checks that the only potentially nonzero term of the $\partial_z$ component of the acceleration of $\gamma_0$ is
$$
\Gamma^z_{xx}(\gamma_0(t)) x_0'(t) ^2 = -e^{2z_0(t)}x_0'(t)^2 = -1,
$$
which is nonzero.
Hence, $\gamma_0$ does not satisfies the equation of geodesics.

Even more: There are no nonconstant length-minimizing geodesic loops in $M$.
